# Подскажите,как работать с указателями си

Tags: c, указатели

Нужно переписать данную программу,только без переменных,а только с помощью указателей.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int max=0, min=0;
    double average, sum = 0;
    int arr[10];
    printf("Введите 10 оценок:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    min = arr[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
        sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    average = sum / 10;
    printf("================================\n");
    printf("максимальная оценка===%d\n", max);
    printf("минимальная оценка===%d\n", min);
    printf("средняя оценка===%.2lf\n", average);
    printf("================================\n");
}
```

На языке Си(без ++), Уж не зашли мне эти указатели.Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// gcc -Wall -std=c11 onlypoint.c -o onlypoint
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    int * max=0, * min=0;
    double average, sum = 0;
    int arr[10];
    printf("Введите 10 оценок:\n");
    for (int * i = arr; i < (&(arr[10])); i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", i );
    }
    min = arr ;
    max = arr ;
    for (int* i = arr; i < (&(arr[10])); i++)
    {
        if (*i > *max)
        {
            max = i;
        }
        if (*i < *min)
        {
            min = i;
        }
        sum = sum + *i;
    }
    average = sum / 10;
    printf("================================\n");
    printf("максимальная оценка===%d\n", *max);
    printf("минимальная оценка===%d\n", *min);
    printf("средняя оценка===%.2lf\n", average);
    printf("================================\n");
}
```